# Use of the '{' character in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a similar function in VBA:

```
=VLOOKUP(“EN878”,CHOOSE({1,2},A2:B5,D2:E5),2,False)
```

In particular, **What is the correct way of using the `{}` character** in VBA?

Every time I try, I get *"Compile error: Invalid Character"*

My code:

**Variables**

```
Table3 = Workbooks("gangstar.xlsx").Worksheets("60 in August 2016-26082016-1137").Range("A1:A1000")
Table2 = Workbooks("gangstar.xlsx").Worksheets("60 in August 2016-26082016-1137").Range("H1:H1000")

For Each cl In Table1
  Sheet1.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Choose({1,2}, Table2, Table3), 2, False)
  Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
Next cl
```

I am able to use the `VLOOKUP` with `CHOOSE` fine in the Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: curly brackets do not have any place in VBA except for inside a string literal.

Comment: Is there an equivilent way to achieve the result of using the curly brackets?

Comment: I've never used the `Choose` function TBH I have no idea what it does. I'm sure there's a corollary way to do this in VBA though.

Comment: What's the intended outcome here?  When I try that formula it always returns the lookup value from the second table (even when only the first table has a match) - what's the array for?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams I am attempting to return a value from the left of the `VLOOKUP` function by using `CHOOSE`.  See here - https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blog/choose-function-arrays-excel/

Comment: OK I see - that's totally new to me...

Comment: @smeapublic, while the `CHOOSE` technique is interesting, the usual approach where the lookup column is to the left of the index column is to use `INDEX(... , MATCH( ... ) )`  In your case `Application.Index(Table3, Application.Match(cl, Table2, False))`

Comment: If nothing else, that would have to be `Application.Choose(...)` not simply `Choose(...)`.

Comment: re: *'Given the A column is to the Left H I can't simply return it using the VLOOKUP function'* - Then use an [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair.

Comment: Upvote for @chrisneilsen - the Index Match was a much better solution.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, which doesn't require modification or recalculation of any cells on the Worksheet:

```
WorksheetFunction.VLookup("EN878", WorksheetFunction.Choose(Array(1, 2), Range("A2:B5"), Range("D2:E5")), 2, False)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the VBA version of OP's worksheet formula. It performs as expected, and answers OP's question.

Comment: No problem.  Just to be clear, I posted my answer before your first edit, in which you added your code. Otherwise, my answer would have been more specific to your code, as was the answer posted by @cyboashu. Perhaps I should not have responded so quickly.

Comment: Yeah... this a valid translation in VBA. Agreed. ++

Comment: @smeapublic this is closest to the correct answer.  In essence, use `Array(1, 2)` instead of `{1,2}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to decide which table to use as Vlookup array you can use `IIf` function. 
Like:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, IIf(cl.column=1, Table2, Table3), 2, False)
```

Comment: Thank you for this - However I just want to return the Value in Table3 using the Table2 in the `VLOOKUP` (`Table3` is just the (A:A) column of a sheet where `Table2` is the (H:H) column of the same sheet).  Given the A column is to the Left H I can't simply return it using the `VLOOKUP` function

Comment: @cyboashu This answer is just plan wrong.  I suggest you delete it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Sheet1.Cells(myRow, myCol).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(...)"` followed by `Sheet1.Cells(myRow, myCol).Calculate`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - Why would you reccoment this?

Comment: You have flexibility to construct complex formulae and string it together this way. The answer that @cyboashu has provided is a better answer to your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but what the OP is doing is not as simple as it appears.

Given this data:

[image]

And this code:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim r

    r = Application.Evaluate("CHOOSE({1,2},A1:B5,E1:F5)")

    Dumper r

End Sub


Sub Dumper(arr)
Dim r, c, s, v
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        s = ""
        For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            v = arr(r, c)
            s = s & vbTab & IIf(IsError(v), "Err!", v)
        Next c
        Debug.Print s
    Next r
End Sub
```

Here's the output:

```
A1  F1
A2  F2
A3  F3
A4  F4
A5  F5
```

Is that what you'd expect ?

Comment: Very close; I would expect the output but the `F` column in the left and the `A` column on the right

Comment: If I use that same formula on the worksheet (as an array) I get the same A:F output

Comment: Never mind - I missed that your VBA example uses single-column ranges...

Answer (score 0):

I would use `range.formulaR1C1` property.

```
Table3AddressR1C1 = Workbooks("gangstar.xlsx").Worksheets("60 in August 2016-26082016-1137").Range("A1:A1000").address(,,xlR1C1, true)
Table2AddressR1C1 = Workbooks("gangstar.xlsx").Worksheets("60 in August 2016-26082016-1137").Range("H1:H1000").address(,,xlR1C1, true)

Sheet1.Range(Cells(1, Dept_Clm), Cells(Table1.rows.count, Dept_Clm)).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLookup(RxCx, Choose({1,2}, Table2AddressR1C1, Table3AddressR1C1), 2, False)"
```